# 12.04, login screen loop

Tags: 12.04, login

Actually my touchpad was not working, so I installed and uninstalled some packages and I did not know what they were. Now I am now getting a login screen and after typing password, it is coming back to the login screen again and again. Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try logging into the Guest account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permissions of your X11 related files, in your home directory. They should belong to you completely.

Use a *virtual terminal* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2 /3/4/5/...</kbd>) to login, and make sure your `~/.Xauthority` file has a `you:yourgroup` ownership. You can use the following command once logged-in :

```
ls ~/.Xauthority -l
```

If the permissions are incorrect, use :

```
sudo chown you:yourgroup ~/.Xauthority
```

(you must be a sudoer)